# Using Smarty 3, Code Igniter 2, and HMVC together with smarty's inheritance?

Tags: php, codeigniter, extend, hmvc, smarty3

I am using Code Igniter, The [HMVC library](http://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc), and Smarty with [this library](http://ilikekillnerds.com/2010/11/using-smarty-3-in-codeigniter-2-a-really-tiny-ci-library/).

Smarty is working fine by default, however if I try to use smarty's inheritance feature ( `{extends file="master.tpl"}`) then we run into an issue.

The extends feature does not look in the module views folder for the extended file (in the above's case `master.tpl`), instead it only looks in the `application/views/` folder and throws an error if it cannot find it.

I could add `APPPATH."modules/smartytest/views"` to the `$config['template_directory']` array in the smarty config file. but that throws an error for each item in the array it checks first for the file. `filemtime(): stat failed for application/views/master.tpl`

and that has the added issue of, if I have three modules all the the array and the modules all have a master.tpl then no matter what module I call the extend from it will load the first one found.

So, is there a way to get smarty's extend function to behave nicely with the HMVC modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, found a working solution,

in `My_Parser.php` edit the block at line 30 so it reads:

```
// Modular Separation / Modular Extensions has been detected
if (method_exists( $this->CI->router, 'fetch_module' ))
{
    $this->_module  = $this->CI->router->fetch_module();
    //add the current module view folder as a template directory
    if ($this->_module !== '')
        $this->CI->smarty->addTemplateDir(APPPATH."modules/".$this->_module.'/views');
}
```

The one drawback of this method is that smarty will look in your application/views folder before the module views folder. if someone knows a solution to that then it would be fantastic.

Comment: protected function _find_view($file) {
        // Ye ol' faithful views folder
        $view_folder = APPPATH . 'views/';

        // The location of our HMVC modules
        $modules_folder = APPPATH . 'modules/';

        // Final path
        $final_path = FALSE;
        
        //add the following line!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        $this->_module = $this->CI->router->fetch_module();
        // Make sure we have a module
        if ($this->_module !== '') {

Comment: i have kind of same kind of problem but not using HMVC with my CI smarty if you can solve it bounty is yours. some time is still remaining.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541382/smarty-templates-with-codeigniter-cant-load-template-when-too-many-directories

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that CI is not checking error_reporting() returns 0, because Smarty is using the @ control operator:
So add the line at the top of the function "_exception_handler":

`if (error_reporting() == 0) return;`

To the "Common.php" file in the "_exception_handler" function (line 469), or create your own function with the same name before calling "CodeIgniter.php" in the index.php file.

Best!